# C++ callback with python through SWIG when the function takes non-trivial arguments?

Tags: c++, python, callback, swig, pyobject

I just read the following section of the "SWIG and Python" tutorial:
http://www.swig.org/Doc1.1/HTML/Python.html#n11

I understand what they do in the example, basically you write a C function that calls python. However, the example provided takes only a double in the argument list, making it rather trivial to build an argument list for python.

I have a C++ callback that has the following signature:

```
Vector (*CALLBACK)(Simulation*, Vector, Vector, double, void*)
```

where Vector and Simulation are my own classes, and void* is for clientData holding a PyObject (as used in the example)

I know that SWIG wraps both the Vector and Simulation classes, because I can create them in a python shell. The only problem is, I have no idea how to transform a Vector argument in the callback function to an appropriate PyObject for the python argument list. SWIG obviously has some way to do this when it wraps the class itself, but I don't know how to accomplish it manually in the function.

Any help much appreciated! 
-Chase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think your question is actually about SWIG; it is purely about Python.  At this level, your problem is simply calling in to Python from C, so you need to study ["Parsing arguments and building values"](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/c-api/arg.html?highlight=py_buildvalue) in the Python documentation.  (Also ["Extending and Embedding the Python interpreter"](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/extending/).)